EBAY API: how to make request "ebay motors 6000" category and get the year?
I tried to make a request, but there is no such function (6000 - car category, but without filter "year")
https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?q=mustang&category_ids=6000&compatibility_filter=Year:1969;Make:Ford;&limit=3
Error:
"errorId": 12506,
"domain": "API_BROWSE",
"category": "REQUEST",
"message": "The category ID submitted does not support fitment."

After that, I made a request for a specific car and received a response with the year of manufacture
https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item/v1|145700595106|0
"localizedAspects": [
    {
        "type": "STRING",
        "name": "Year",
        "value": "1969"
    },


I'm doing a project for graduation and my program needs to search for cars over 30 years old (oldtimers), so I really need a filter at the stage of searching by category. Can you help me?
how do I use a year filter to search in the 6000 category?

i used these docs:
https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/resources/item_summary/methods/search#s0-1-22-6-7-7-6-ReturnItemsthatareCompatiblewiththeKeywordandVehicle-9
https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/resources/item/methods/getItemsByItemGroup#h2-samples

I make this project with python, but for tests I use postman.
I've tried all combinations of filters in the query, but none of them return the vehicle year for category 6000 (cars).
What’s strange is that for the category “brakes” (from examples on ebay) such a filter works
Thank you
